# Moshi Unable to create converter for class with generic

Tags: java, android, generics, retrofit, moshi

Some of my server response for success are:

> {
>       "error": null,
>       "data": null
>   }

My model is:

```
public class BaseResponse<E > {

    @Json(name = "error")
    public ErrorModel error;

    @Json(name = "data")
    public E data;
}
```

If my endpoint is

```
@POST("user")
Call<BaseResponse<String>> createUser(@Body Credentials credentials);
```

This works, but the type String is useless as data will always be null. But if i make it:

```
@POST("user")
Call<BaseResponse> createUser(@Body Credentials credentials);
```

I got crash at

```
Call<BaseResponse> call = apiService.createUser(creds);
```

full log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for 
    class common.model.responses.BaseResponse for method MyEndpoints.createUser
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a Class, ParameterizedType, 
   or GenericArrayType, but <null> is of type null
  at com.squareup.moshi.Types.getRawType(Types.java:167)
  at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.createFieldBindings(ClassJsonAdapter.java:83)
  at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:75)
  at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:100)
  at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.createFieldBindings(ClassJsonAdapter.java:91)
  at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:75)
  at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:100)
  at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(MoshiConverterFactory.java:91)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:330)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
  at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:736)
 ...
```

Comment: can you add your original response means with dummy value

Comment: { "error": null, "data": null }  is the exact response for this case

Comment: Post more of your stacktrace.

Comment: Also, maybe you want `BaseResponse<Void>`? but i'd still be interested in seeing the stacktrace here.

Comment: Ah, I see why. There's no way to know the type of the `E` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific error surfaces because there is no way to know the type of the `E` field, since it was not specified in the raw type usage.

Since you know that this field will always be null, the best solution is to use a different type (that lacks the field) to clarify this.

If you really cannot use a different type, you could use `Void` as the generic type argument. You would need to register a JsonAdapter on your Moshi instance for the Void field to be deserialized, though: `new Moshi.Builder().add(VOID_JSON_ADAPTER).build()`

```
static final Object VOID_JSON_ADAPTER = new Object() {
  @FromJson Void fromJson(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    return reader.nextNull();
  }

  @ToJson void toJson(JsonWriter writer, Void v) throws IOException {
    writer.nullValue();
  }
};
```

But, using a different type makes the most sense.

Comment: I have custom callback that have BaseResponse as generic, that handles the errors and preffer to have only one root response class. I thought about the void but it seems implemented the adapter wrong

Comment: I have one quck question for the Adapter- The ones ive seen so far have String parameter, your way there is JsonWriter.  Are they the same thing?

Comment: The writer is a little bit clearer and faster. There are other ways to make these composed adapters with delegated types, yes.

valid `@FromJson` formats: https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/76f50df2ccb59c72c647bfa5feea953ccf457be8/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/AdapterMethodsFactory.java#L259

valid `@ToJson` formats:
https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/76f50df2ccb59c72c647bfa5feea953ccf457be8/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/AdapterMethodsFactory.java#L194